# What is the minimum requirement of physical RAM if I want to set JVM virtual RAM 8GB?

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, srl

Recently I am trying to Integrate mateplus a semantic role labeling tool for my work. It requires upto 8GB JVM virtual RAM for heap memory. can anybody help me out that If I want to do that, what is the minimum requirement of physical RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to have at least 8GB RAM, but the JVM's are allocating virtual memory, not physical memory. The OS will assign physical memory to virtual memory as necessary and efficient. Modern operating systems can allow virtual memory consumption to significantly exceed physical memory. This may or may not lead to poor performance, depending on the working set size -- roughly how much of the virtual memory is actually accessed.
So in simple words if OS have less physical memory than JVM need it will swap it on hard disk which will affect performance.